# looping an array issue with working out when to input HTML

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, count, modulus

I am trying to loop through an array, and every 3 loops create a new row, however I am having difficulty getting it to work, currently my code looks like this,

```
<li class="row">
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) : ?>
                <div class="grid_8">
                    <div class="candidate <?php if ($i % 3 == 2) echo "end"; ?>">
                        <div class="model_image shadow_50"></div>
                        <dl>
                            <dt><?php echo $results[$i]['first_name']; ?> <?php echo $results[$i]['surname']; ?></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <?php echo $results[$i]['talent']; ?>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><?php echo anchor("/candidates/card/" . strtolower($results[$i]['first_name']) . "-" . strtolower($results[$i]['surname']), "View Details", array('class' => 'details')); ?></li>
                                    <li><?php echo anchor("/candidates/card/" . strtolower($results[$i]['first_name']) . "-" . strtolower($results[$i]['surname']), "View Showreel", array('class' => 'showreel')); ?></li>
                                    <li><?php echo anchor("/candidates/card/" . strtolower($results[$i]['first_name']) . "-" . strtolower($results[$i]['surname']), "Shortlist", array('class' => 'shortlist')); ?></li>
                                </ul>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php if ($i % 3 == 3) : ?>
                 </li><li class="row">   
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
```

However this just creates one row, and with all my results in it, whereas it should be 1 li with a class of row, and then 3 .grid_8 divs and then another row.

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your modulus equation. The remainder will never reach 3, and will be a pattern of (0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2). So you change it to equal 2.

```
        if ($i % 3 == 2)
```

Comment: Is it possible to detect when the loop has reached the last record?

Comment: take the max limit out of the for loop and add an increment counter. Then you can use the increment counter to add either the </li> or <li> via an if/switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a counter to keep track of where you are row wise in your loop it may make things easier.

```
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
    if ($count == 0) {
        echo "<li class=\"row\">";
    }

    echo "all your middle stuff";
    $count++;

    if ($count == 4) {
        echo "</li>";
        $count = 0;
    }
}

//just make sure we dont need to add a /li
if ($count % 3 != 0) 
    echo "</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only presume you have an enclosing

somewhere that you haven't shown us. Nonetheless it appears as if you're missing your final  so your browser is confused.

Answer (score 0):

It just cant be like this `if ($i % 3 == 3)` - `$i % 3` is always in range `0..2`.
Maybe you `if ($i % 3 == 0)` - it will be "every third $i"